# TCP connection bridge/proxy-alike for logging

Tags: proxy, tcp, bridge

**The simplified scenario:**

I have a phone system which logs out every single operation on port 6543.
I also have a listener (existing application) which connects to the phone system (a linux box) and deals with all the data (byte stream) coming from that phone system. ***The phone system can only have ONE connection at a time.***

**What I need:**

A way to connect to the phone system and dump the byte stream to a file and let the listener application (which I have no control on but possibility to configure the IP and the port it will connect to) connect to my process so it works as if it was directly connected to the phone system.

**What I want to do:**

1. Connect to phone system and dump the data to a file (using "the utility" that I want you to suggest me).
2. Allow the listener process to connect to "the utility" so it can semalessly continue to work as usual.

There must be something clever I just can't think/know of to do this?

What I call "the utility" could be a bash script, a un*x utility, some clever gnu tool, any existing github project, etc.

Comment: Please xplain what you mean with "Allow the listener process to connect to "me" so it can semalessly continue to work as usual". What is "me"? What have you used to make the listener?

Comment: Tried to reformulate the whole thing... thank you for asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I found so far: 
**(netcat might be what I was looking for!)**

`mkfifo phonesystem.fifo`

Script :

```
#!/bin/bash
PHONE_IP=192.168.167.166
PHONE_PORT=6543
LISTENING_PORT=${PHONE_PORT}
CURRENT=$(date +%F#%T | sed -e 's/:/./g')

cat phonesystem.fifo | nc -l -p ${LISTENING_PORT} | tee ${CURRENT}.ApplicationListener.log | nc ${PHONE_IP} ${PHONE_PORT} | tee ${CURRENT}.PhoneSystem.log 1> phonesystem.fifo
```

I will then configure my "listener application" to connect to my box IP at port `6543` instead of connecting it to the phone system IP at port `6543`...

***Wonder if I could multiplex the output so I could connect multiple time to my box and get the stream for all connections...***